# In pyspark, is it possible to fillna with another column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say there is a RDD that looks like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----+
| age|best_guess_age| name|
+----+--------------+-----+
|  23|            23|Alice|
|null|            18|  Bob|
|  34|            32|  Tom|
|null|            40|Linda|
+----+--------------+-----+
```

Where we want to fill the `age` column with `best_guess_age` column whenever it is null.

The [`fillna` command](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) requires an actual value to replace the na's, we can't simply pass in a column.

How to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) function; By doing `coalesce('age', 'best_guess_age')`, it will take values from `age` column if it's not null, otherwise from `best_guess_age` column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
df.withColumn('age', coalesce('age', 'best_guess_age')).show()
+---+--------------+-----+
|age|best_guess_age| name|
+---+--------------+-----+
| 23|            23|Alice|
| 18|            18|  Bob|
| 34|            32|  Tom|
| 40|            40|Linda|
+---+--------------+-----+
```